# Delphi 2010 - Overbyte ICS FTP upload with progress bar

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm using the ICS Overbyte FTP for uploading a file. I want to display a progressbar and a speed indicator in order to trqack and estimate large file uploads. How can I do that? 
Also after the upload is completed i want to delete the file from my hdd.
Here is the code that i'm using right now to upload to a ftp server.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ftp:Tftpclient;
begin
    Ftp:=Tftpclient.Create(NIL);
    Ftp.UserName:='';
    Ftp.PassWord:='';
    Ftp.HostName:='';
    Ftp.LocalFileName:='d:\fpc-2.6.4.i386-win32.exe';
    Ftp.HostDirName:='/';
    Ftp.HostFileName := extractfilename(ftp.LocalFileName);

    ftp.BandwidthLimit:=0;
    Ftp.Passive := True;
    FTP.Binary := True;
    ftp.MultiThreaded:=true;

    try
    ftp.connect;

    if ftp.Connected then
     begin

        memo1.lines.add(datetimetostr(now)+' - connected to '+ftp.hostname+' => '+ftp.LastResponse);

        Ftp.put;
        memo1.lines.add(datetimetostr(now)+' - loading file "'+ftp.hostfilename+'" => '+ftp.LastMultiResponse);

        Ftp.Quit;
        memo1.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now)+' - closing connection =>'+ftp.lastResponse);
     end;

    finally
    ftp.free;

    end;
end;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TFtpClient` has an [`OnProgress`/`OnProgress64`](http://www.mestdagh.biz/ics/help/TFtpClient.html#OnProgress1D) event:

> OnProgress:   Display the current file transfer progression.
>
> ```
> property OnProgress : procedure(Sender : TObject; Count : LongInt; var Abort : Boolean) of object;
> ```
>
> Unit
>   FtpCli

You need to create the `TFtpClient` object and assign an event handler to it, then you can perform your `Put()` command and receive status about the upload.

```
procedure TForm1.Log(const S: String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(Now) + ' - ' + S);
  Memo1.Update;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ftp: TFtpClient;
begin
  Ftp := TFtpclient.Create(nil);
  try
    Ftp.OnProgress := FtpProgress;

    Ftp.UserName := ...;
    Ftp.PassWord := ...;
    Ftp.HostName := ...;
    Ftp.LocalFileName := 'D:\fpc-2.6.4.i386-win32.exe';
    Ftp.HostDirName := '/';
    Ftp.HostFileName := ExtractFileName(Ftp.LocalFileName);
    Ftp.BandwidthLimit := 0;
    Ftp.Passive := True;
    Ftp.Binary := True;
    Ftp.MultiThreaded := true;

    Log('connecting to ' + Ftp.HostName);
    if not Ftp.Connect then
    begin
      Log('unable to connect to ' + Ftp.HostName + ' => ' + Ftp.LastResponse);
      Exit;
    end;

    try
      Log('connected to ' + Ftp.HostName);

      Log('uploading file "' + Ftp.HostFileName + '");
      if Ftp.Put then begin
        Log('uploaded file "' + Ftp.HostFileName + '"');
      end else begin
        Log('unable to upload file "' + Ftp.HostFileName + '" => ' + Ftp.LastMultiResponse);
      end;
    finally
      Log('closing connection');
      Ftp.Quit;
    end;
  finally
    Ftp.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FtpProgress(Sender : TObject; Count : LongInt; var Abort : Boolean);
begin
  // calculate size transmitted/remaining, speed, and time remaining as needed...
end;
```

If you use `TFtpClient` in asynchronous mode, assign a handler to the [`OnRequestDone`](http://www.mestdagh.biz/ics/help/TFtpClient.html#OnRequestDone20) event as well, and do not free the object until everything is finished.

> OnRequestDone:    Trigged when a command is completed.
>
> ```
> property OnRequestDone : procedure(Sender : TObject; RqType : TFtpRequest; Error : Word) of object;
> ```
>
> Unit
>   FtpCli
>
> Description
>   When an command is completed, this event is called. Use this event to know when an async command is completed and then call the next one.

```
var
  Ftp: TFtpClient = nil;

procedure TForm1.Log(const S: String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(Now) + ' - ' + S);
  Memo1.Update;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Ftp = nil then
  begin
    Ftp := TFtpClient.Create(Self);
    Ftp.OnProgress := FtpProgress;
    Ftp.OnRequestDone := FtpRequestDone;
  end;

  Ftp.UserName := ...;
  Ftp.PassWord := ...;
  Ftp.HostName := ...;
  Ftp.LocalFileName := 'D:\fpc-2.6.4.i386-win32.exe';
  Ftp.HostDirName := '/';
  Ftp.HostFileName := ExtractFileName(Ftp.LocalFileName);
  Ftp.BandwidthLimit := 0;
  Ftp.Passive := True;
  Ftp.Binary := True;
  Ftp.MultiThreaded := true;

  Log('connecting to ' + Ftp.HostName);
  Ftp.ConnectAsync;
end;

procedure TForm1.FtpProgress(Sender : TObject; Count : LongInt; var Abort : Boolean);
begin
  // calculate size transmitted/remaining, speed, and time remaining as needed...
end;

procedure TForm1.FtpRequestDone(Sender : TObject; RqType : TFtpRequest; Error : Word);
begin
  case RqType of
    ftpConnectAsync: begin
      if Error = 0 then begin
        Log('connected to ' + Ftp.HostName);
        Log('uploading file "' + Ftp.HostFileName + '");
        Ftp.PutAsync;
      end else begin
        Log('unable to connect to ' + Ftp.HostName + ' => ' + Ftp.LastResponse);
        FreeAndNil(ftp);
      end;
    end;
    ftpPutAsync: begin
      if Error = 0 then begin
        Log('uploaded file "' + Ftp.HostFileName + '"');
      end else begin
        Log('unable to upload file "' + Ftp.HostFileName + '" => ' + Ftp.LastMultiResponse);
      end;
      Log('closing connection');
      Ftp.QuitAsync;
    end;
    ftpQuitAsync: begin
      FreeAndNil(ftp);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Could you please post an exemple?

Comment: Thank you Remy. The code above connects to the server but does not start the upload.

Comment: What output is being logged?

Comment: SERVER OUTPUT:Connected, sending welcome message...
220 **********
USER ***
331 Password required for ***
PASS ********
230 Logged on

Comment: I meant, what is being written to your Memo at each step of the above code?  If `Connect()` returning True or False?  Is `Put()` returning True or False?

Comment: In the memo nothing is logged. Because in the actual state the logging is written only after the successful upload of te file. But the upload does not take place.

Comment: It has to be logging something in the Memo, at every stage, not jut uploading.  Even if the main message loop were blocked during the upload, the text should appear once control returns to the message loop.

Comment: Got it: in the button1.click i had to change ftp.connect to Ftp.ConnectAsync. Also in the FtpRequestDone i changed the case of ftpopenasync with ftpconnectasync.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71413/discussion-between-user2858981-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: Thanks for posting the synchronous and the asynchronous solution.